# Laravel 8 customise email verification link

Tags: php, laravel

I am writing an API using `Laravel 8` .. I have followed the documentation for implementing `email` verification, but I want to modify the link that is sent with the `email`.

My API and Frontend are completely seperate, so the link that `Laravel` creates needs to be changed to point to my frontend.

I have implemented as per in my `AuthServiceProvider`;

```
public function boot(): void
{
    $this->registerPolicies();

    VerifyEmail::toMailUsing(function ($notifiable, $url) {
        return (new MailMessage)
            ->subject('Verify Email Address')
            ->line('Click the button below to verify your email address.')
            ->action('Verify Email Address', $url);
    });
}
```

I am working on localhost so please excuse the URL's .. But the URL that laravel outputs is as follows;

```
http://localhost/api/email/verify/217gd8b5b-1e23-4450-8b3b-a9c7610b16ed?expires=1625027126&hash=24499f2ba77786684dab8f4d71832d71d86be69e0&signature=e5ac2a5aa6c941ce36ef70d842d8efcea7ed79fc72597a1e44cd36c566fd71b34
```

I need to change that to something like;

```
http://localhost:3000/verifyemail/217gd8b5b-1e23-4450-8b3b-a9c7610b16ed?expires=1625027126&hash=24499f2ba77786684dab8f4d71832d71d86be69e0&signature=e5ac2a5aa6c941ce36ef70d842d8efcea7ed79fc72597a1e44cd36c566fd71b34
```

Is that possible at all?

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/verification#the-email-verification-handler), you need to set up a route with a specific naming convention; `verification.verify`.

You can add this route to your `web` routes like so:

```php
Route::get('/verifyemail/{id}/{hash}', function () {
    return;
})->name('verification.verify');
```

Laravel doesn't care that the actual frontend is detached for parsing the link.

Second, you need to verify the request via your API from your detached frontend. You need to forward the request to the API and use the `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\EmailVerificationRequest` as the Request instance to fulfill the verification.

The following example is just a pseudo example, as this might require some tinkering depending on your frontend implementation, but you would hopefully get the idea. This route of course belongs to your `api` routes.

```php
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\EmailVerificationRequest;

Route::get('/verifyemail/{id}/{hash}', function (EmailVerificationRequest $request) {
    $request->fulfill();
    
    // Just return a 201 (or 200 if it pleases you better)
    return response()->json(null, 201);

// Don't use the verification.verify route name here
})->middleware(['auth', 'signed']);
```

That should do it.

Comment: Hey, thank you for posting that. As i am not using any web routes, do I need to add the first example you have given?

Comment: Yes, you will need to have a web route for this specifically, as I mentioned. The reason is that `web` routes do _not_ get prefixed with `/api` in the URI.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you